# Are there any Jabber (XMPP) apps out there that support jabber conferencing? 

Tags: applications, instant-messaging, xmpp

I've tried several, and so far I can't get one that will just work with my work jabber + conferencing (jabber 'rooms').  They all seem mostly clunky.  Does anyone have a rec that has worked well for them for me to try?

Comment: Can you list the apps you've already tried?

Comment: Good Idea.. my battery is dead but I'll add this info as soon as I recharge.

Comment: "List of X" questions are generally off-topic for this site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm using [Trillian for Android](http://www.trillian.im/learn/tour-android.html). As far as I know it's still in beta, but worked well for me so far. Though I did't use it in any extreme situations yet. Oh, and it doesn't handle calls yet.

**Edit:** It's out of beta... and now you have to pay for it. If you don't like that, or don't have the money (or you can't buy apps from the Market like me) you should use something else.

Comment: Trillian seems to work pretty well. It's a bummer that you have to create an account on their website, but, for the moment, it will do.

Comment: All multiprotocol clients I know force you to register an account. It would be nice to have a client like... Pidgin for Android. But I guess it just not going to happen. Or at least not in our lifetime :)

Comment: @ytg I dunno... I wouldn't be too sure of that... http://csclub.uwaterloo.ca/~dtbartle/pidroid/

Comment: @Aeo "This is mostly just a proof-of-concept." But I would be happy to see something like that actually working on my phone.

Comment: @ytg and @Aeo have you checked out Gibberbot? Free software, multi-protocol. Active developer community. https://market.android.com/details?id=info.guardianproject.otr.app.im

Comment: @Amanda I think you should add it as an answer. (Even if it won't work for _me_ because I use other protocols too.)

Comment: Trillian for Android is currently free. http://www.trillian.im/android/

Answer (score 6):

I'm using [Gibberbot](https://market.android.com/details?id=info.guardianproject.otr.app.im). It is worth taking a look at. Free software, multi-protocol. [Active developer community](https://guardianproject.info/).  Definitely still in beta but that doesn't mean it won't do what you need.

Comment: Very cool... this could be what I'm looking for!  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'm using [IM Plus](http://www.appbrain.com/app/im-plus/de.shapeservices.impluslite), which was the only thing I could get to work with our Jabber server.  It's been very solid for me and they have a decent forum community, too.  FWIW, I liked it enough to pay the $5 for it.

Answer (score 1):

[Xabber](http://www.xabber.com/) supports MUC/conferencing

Answer (score 1):

[Jabiru](https://market.android.com/details?id=net.mzet.jabiru) is another one.